# Determine the boundary of the set: $ \left \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}: m, n \in\mathbb{N} \right\}. $

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Determine the  boundary of the set: 
$$ \left \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}: m, n \in\mathbb{N} \right\}. $$

Let's show that $ \partial A = \{0 \} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} : n, m \in \mathbb{N} \} $.

$ \Rightarrow $] If $ x = 0 $, then for all $ r> 0 $, $ B_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset $ then if $ r = 2 \epsilon, $ such that $ B_r (0 = (- 2 \epsilon, 2 \epsilon) $ and for the Archimedean property there is $ m $ such that $ 0 <\frac{1}{m} <\epsilon $ and $ n $ such that $ \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m} $. That is, $ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} < 2 \epsilon = r $. On the other hand, note that if $ x = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} $ for any $ n, m \in \mathbb{N} $ then for all $ r> 0 $, $ B_r (x) \cap A \neq \emptyset $.

Also $ B_r (x) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset $, since there is an irrational number $ q\in B_r (x) $ and $ q\in A^c $.

Then $\{0 \} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} | n, m\in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \partial A $.

$ \Leftarrow $] Let's demonstrate it by opposite demostration, that is, if $ x \notin \{0 \} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} | n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ then $ x\notin \partial A $.

I'm not sure if the opposite is the correct way. Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: $\{\frac{1}{n}:n \in \mathbb N\}$ is also in $\partial A$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have to add $\{\frac 1n\}$ because, for example, $\frac 17+\frac1n$ tends to $\frac17+0=\frac17$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Fix $x\in (0,1)\setminus (A\cup \{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\})$. We wish to argue $x\not\in \partial A$.

There exists a unique $N$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{N+1}<x<\frac{1}{N}
$$
Now there is a unique $M$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{M+1}<x<\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{M}
$$